# What's the most efficient way to sort an array with a single series of inversions?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, haskell, recursion, graph-algorithm

I have a list of integers that has already been sorted in a descending order, but a function that takes the value of the first element (let's call that `x`) and maps `subtract 1`  to `x` values of the rest of the list (excluding the first element) is applied. (I am trying to implement the recursive algorithm to check for [a graphic sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphicSequence.html).)

```
list1 = [4,4,3,2,2,2,2,1] --an example of a nonincreasing list
newList = (/s -> map (subtract 1) (fst s) ++ snd s) $ splitAt (head list1) (tail list1)
                       --newList == [3,2,1,1,2,2,1]
--only these four need to be swapped     | | | |             
sortedList = sortFunction newList --[3,2,2,2,1,1,1]
```

The new list needs to be sorted again in a descending order for the next step of recursion. I've tried using `Data.List.sort`, but this becomes fairly slow for large lists, as it is applied for every level of recursion.

The nature of mapping `subtract 1` to the beginning of a list of nonincreasing integers means that there is really only one spot at where there is an inversion: for example, in the previous code, the first two `1`'s only need to be exchanged with the next two `2`'s in order to sort the list.

What's the most efficient (i.e. fastest) way to do this sorting? Also, is there a more efficient data structure to use instead of lists for this job?

Comment: merging is the conventional way to combine two sorted lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be better off doing run-length encoding. Then you don't have to dig very far to keep the list sorted.

(WARNING: untested Haskell code.) A function

```
rlEncode xs = [(length xs', head xs') | xs' <- reverse $ group $ sort xs]
```

turns `[4,4,3,2,2,2,2,1]` into `[(2,4),(1,3),(4,2),(1,1)]`. Then we can write a "constructor"

```
rlCons (n, x) [] = [(n, x)]
rlCons (n, x) rle@((n', x') : rle')
    | x == x' = (n + n', x) : rle'
    | otherwise = (n, x) : rle
```

and a "destructor"

```
rlUncons [] = Nothing
rlUncons ((1, x) : rle) = Just (x, rle)
rlUncons ((n, x) : rle) = Just (x, (n - 1, x) : rle)
```

for run-length encoded lists. Then `isGraphic`, in its simplest and least efficient form, looks like this.

```
isGraphic [] = True
isGraphic rle = fromMaybe False $ do
    (d, rle') <- rlUncons rle
    rle'' <- deflate d rle'
    return $ isGraphic rle''

deflate 0 rle = Just rle
deflate _d [] = Nothing
deflate _d [(_,0)] = Nothing
deflate d ((n, d') : rle)
    | d < n = Just $ rlCons (n - d, d') $ rlCons (d, d' - 1) rle
    | otherwise = liftM (rlCons (n, d' - 1)) $ deflate (d - n) rle
```

Comment: @JonathanJeffrey As the post author, I was able to unilaterally approve your suggested edit, but you shouldn't make a habit of changing code in suggested edits, because the people reviewing them have no context and are instructed not to approve edits that appear to change the author's intent.

Comment: Ok, thanks! (New to SO.) As a side note, I think this might be also sped up by using `mod` in the deflate function to skip over recursively deflating the same number, i.e. adding the case ``d == d' && d < n = Just $ rlCons ((n - d) `mod` (d + 1), d) $ rlCons (((n - d) `div` (d+1)) * d, d - 1) $ rlCons (d, d' - 1) rle``, to deflate, although `rlCons (0,_) rle = rle` would need to be added to the definition of rlCons. Thanks for the help!